# Maven plugins and resource substitution

Tags: maven, plugins, lifecycle

I have a regular requirement to execute several goals in Maven so I decided to write a plugin for it. It seemed easiest to define a new lifecycle for this, each phase executing the relevant plugin goal. I need to pass configuration to the plugin, specifically a directory and a version number.

I found that if I use a variable in lifecycle.xml, such as ${projname.directory}, the variable appears to be resolved not at plugin compile time but at project compile time. I'm guessing that lifecycle.xml is used within the project and not touched by the plugin. Is there any reference for understanding exactly how this works?

Also, I'd like to be able to use a default directory name if the projname.directory property is not set - storing this in the plugin source somewhere. I have no idea how to go about this - is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks,
-Dave

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more cause it sounds like you are going wrong direction. Why a plugin to execute several goals? executions does not fit?

Comment: Maybe I'm not taking the right approach. I have several projects (probably will grow) and each one wants to do the same thing at certain times (outside of the usual build cycle). I thought the best way to encapsulate this was to define a plugin which contains the common logic, and simply include the plugin inside each project's POM. Is that not a good thing to do?

Comment: What would you like to do? And what does it mean outside of the build life cycle?

Comment: We have a large library of C++ dlls, which we use Java bindings for to run functions. These need to be installed alongside the Java but they're too big to distribute inside the jar of each project. My current solution is to zip them up and on the target machine grab the zip from Nexus and unpack it into an appropriate (known) directory for use within the Java. This task only needs to happen for new machines or new versions of the C++, hence outside of the usual Java build cycle.